# neo4j-rest-graphdb not able to handle transactions with Neo4J 2.0.x

Tags: java, rest, transactions, neo4j

I'm using neo4j-rest-graphdb 2.0.1 (2.0.3 is not available as of today) to access a standalone Neo4j Community 2.0.3 REST Server.
In particular, I want to be able to use neo4j-rest-graphdb to group queries into transactions.
The [README](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/java-rest-binding) says:

> In 1.8 it tries to collect all operations within a tx as a
>   batch-operation which will then be executed on the server.
>
> This has the implication that the results retrieved within that "tx"
>   are not immediately available but only after you called tx.success and
>   tx.finish

However, the following (simplest possible) code that uses a transaction

```
db = new RestGraphDatabase(<SOMEURL>, <SOMEUSER>, <SOMEPASSWORD>);
System.setProperty(Config.CONFIG_BATCH_TRANSACTION,"true");

Transaction tx = db.beginTx();

// line where exception is thrown    
ResourceIterable<Node> it = db.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(DynamicLabel.label(type), "@id", id);

Node result = Iterables.getOnlyElement(it);

tx.success();
tx.finish();
tx.close();
```

throws a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: received org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult@5acc5fb1
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.toNodeIterableResult(ExecutingRestAPI.java:284)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.getNodesByLabelAndProperty(ExecutingRestAPI.java:273)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.getNodesByLabelAndProperty(RestAPIFacade.java:344)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(RestGraphDatabase.java:147)   
    at {the marked line in the above code}
```

debugging yields that the fields of the RequestResult that is returned by the Neo4j DB have the following values:

- status: 0
- batchId: 1
- batchResult: true
- string: ""
- all other fields: null

When I set `System.setProperty(Config.CONFIG_BATCH_TRANSACTION,"false");` instead of "true", no exception is thrown and the request is returned correctly with correct contents, however not in a transactional context.
Why is that the case? 
How can I get (batch-based) transactions with neo4j-rest-graphdb to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319464/neo4j-transaction-not-rolling-back/) and it looks like the library in question has been discontinued. Transactions are only supported over HTTP with cypher endpoint. [Spring data Neo4j](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/) seems to be the way to go. Otherwise you can use the JDBC layer ([Example project here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/developer-resources/tree/gh-pages/language-guides/java/jdbc)). I just learned this today and I have to change my entire project's code to now use Spring. Sigh.