# neo4j transaction not rolling back

Tags: java, transactions, neo4j

I am using neo4j 2.1.7 with java.

```
    try(Transaction transaction = this.graphDatabaseService.beginTx())
    {
        Node user = this.graphDatabaseService.createNode();
        user.setProperty("userId", userId);
        transaction.failure();
    }
```

So I am getting the object of GraphDatabaseService and creating a new transaction and marking it to rollback. According to their javadocs:

> **void failure()**
>
> Marks this transaction as failed, which means that it will
>   unconditionally be rolled back when close() is called. Once this
>   method has been invoked, it doesn't matter if success() is invoked
>   afterwards -- the transaction will still be rolled back.

But I see that the node gets created no matter what. I tried `throwing an exception`. I also tried `not calling transaction.success()` at all. Still I see that the changes get committed and not rolled back. I am not sure of this behaviour and would like an explanation. Thanks.

If you must know, I am trying to build a commit() function with nested transactions such that if any operation fail within the inner transactions, the parent transaction must fail too. However, in the process I found that no matter what I do, the transactions are getting committed.

**Update 1:**

The embedded version of neo4j works fine. The rest version is causing this trouble. I am using this package for rest:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-rest-graphdb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No transactions over REST, at least not for that old version.

There are only transactions over HTTP with the new Cypher Endpoint.

That library is discontinued, I recommend that you use e.g. the JDBC driver or the new implementation that comes with Spring Data REST.

Comment: Hi. I was studying neo4j-jdbc code and I am having trouble understanding how to do a batch transaction. I am reluctant on using spring because I don’t have a POJO model. I just need to run some queries and get the results in simple datatypes - No overhead of ORM type tools. Also JDBC vs Spring, which one would be more updated with Neo4j. I am thinking to moving to 2.2 version and in future I would move to a new version as soon as they become available.